# Xcode says CFBundleShortVersionString missing, but it's in my plist

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, itunes

Good day

currently im having problems uploading my build to itunes connect it keeps on saying this.

[image]

but I already have it in my plist

[image]

what seems to be the problem here?

BTW I build my xcode project using Unity

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just the other day. Try making it version 1.0 and build 2. That fixed it for me.